# ¿Existen diferencias entre SCSS y CSS?

Tags: css, sass, scss

Estoy empezando a trabajar con Ionic y hace uso de una extensión llamada  scss que es para los estilos al igual que css, y a pesar de que he visto que trabajan igual, me gustaría saber si existen algunas diferencias notables entre sí.

Comment: SCSS es un compilador de CSS, algo como typescript de javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS es el lenguaje de estilo que cualquier navegador entiende para diseñar páginas web.

*SCSS es un tipo especial de archivo para SASS, un programa escrito en Ruby que ensambla hojas de estilo CSS para un navegador, y para información SASS agrega muchas funciones adicionales a las variables de tipo CSS, anidamiento y más, lo que hace que escribir CSS sea más fácil y más rápido. Los archivos SCSS son procesados ​​por el servidor que ejecuta una aplicación web para generar un CSS tradicional que su navegador puede entender*

El SCSS es la sintaxis de CSS pero con todas las ventajas de SASS (puedes declarar variables, hacer anidamiento entre otras cosas).

Comment: Muchas gracias, tal vez una pregunta obvia pero mejor a quedarse con la duda ¿no?, te agradezco